# Compare using Collections.sort

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I am trying to sort a text file which is separated by tabs and trying to sort by the third field, className.  I am then going to display it in a table.  I wrote the following part, but it is not sorting correctly.  Any ideas as to where I am going wrong?

```
    public void sortFile(){
    BufferedReader reader = null; 
    BufferedWriter writer = null;

    //Create an ArrayList object to hold the lines of input file
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();


    try{
        //Creating BufferedReader object to read the input file
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pupilInfo.txt"));
        //Reading all the lines of input file one by one and adding them into ArrayList
        String currentLine = reader.readLine();
        while (currentLine != null){
            lines.add(currentLine);
            currentLine = reader.readLine();
        } 


            Collections.sort(lines, (String s1, String s2) -> {
            s1 = lines.get(0);
            s2 = lines.get(1);
            String [] line1 = s1.split("\t");
            String [] line2 = s2.split("\t");
            String classNameLine1 = line1[2];
            String classNameLine2 = line2[2];
            System.out.println("classname1=" + classNameLine1);
            System.out.println("classname2=" + classNameLine2);
            int sComp = classNameLine1.compareTo(classNameLine2);
            return sComp;
        });
        //Creating BufferedWriter object to write into output temp file
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("pupilSortTemp.txt"));
        //Writing sorted lines into output file
        for (String line : lines){
            writer.write(line);
            writer.newLine();
        }            
    }catch (IOException e){
    }
    finally{
    //Closing the resources
        try{
            if (reader != null){
                reader.close();
            }
            if(writer != null){
                writer.close();
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
        }
    }  

}
```

Comment: `s1 = lines.get(0); s2 = lines.get(1);` - what the heck are you doing?

Comment: If you delete the two lines that @user2357112 has identified, it would be a good start to fixing your problem.

Comment: The comparator you are passing to `Collections.sort` is already passed in the strings that are to be compared (from your ArrayList<String>), so you don't need to set them manually.  Furthermore, you're actually overwriting the correct values passed in to the comparator.

Comment: I am new to this.  I took out the lines mentioned above.  Thank you for your comments.  It is appreciated.  I will go to a beginner's forum.  I thought maybe I would get some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'ava tried with "comparator".for simplicity my source file is as follows

```
pippo;pluto;paperino
casa;terra;cortile
primo;secondo;terzo

Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    return o1.split(";")[2].compareTo(o2.split(";")[2]);

                }
            };

            lines.sort(comparator);
```

final output

```
[casa;terra;cortile, pippo;pluto;paperino, primo;secondo;terzo]
```

sorted on third field!

Comment: Thank you for "kindly" answering my question.   This option works for me.